# Symbol Creation in Z3 Java API

Tags: z3

I am new to Z3, so excuse me if the question sounds too easy. I have two questions regrading constants in Z3 Java API.

1. How does creation of constants happen internally? To understand that I started by tracking 
   `public BitVecExpr mkBVConst(String, int)` down to `public StringSymbol mkSymbol(String)` which eventually calls `Native.mkStringSymbol(var1.nCtx(), var2)` which generates the variable in `var3` in this line `long var3 = INTERNALmkStringSymbol(var0, var2);`

now because `INTERNALmkStringSymbol' is native I can't see its source. I am wondering about how does it operate. Does anyone know how does it work? Where to view its source?

2. Another thing I am confused about is the scoping of constants using the API. In the interactive Z3, it is maintained through matching push and pop but through the API, I am not sure how scoping is defined and managed.

Any insights or guidance is much appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

1. Z3 is open source, you can view and download the source from https://github.com/z3prover/z3.git. Symbols in Z3 are defined in src/util/symbol.h. You will see that symbols are similar to LISP atoms: they persist through the lifetime of the dll and are unique. So two symbols with the same name will be pointer-equal. The Java API calls into the C API, which is declared in src/api/z3_api.h. The directory src/api contains the API functions, including those that create symbols. When you create an expression constant, such as mkBVConst, it is an expression that is also pointer-unique (if you create the same mkBVConst twice, the unmanaged pointers will be equal. The Java pointers are not the same, but equality testing exploits all of this).
2. The Solver object has push and pop methods. You can add constraints to the solver object. The life-time of constraints follow the push/pop nesting: a constraint is active until there is a pop that removes the scope where the constraint was added.

Comment: Thanks @Nikola, this is really helpfulj. But for the second point, you are talking about scoping for constraints not constants. Do this mean that constants are global? Thanks again!